# Adding selection to List Box based upon prior List Box Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a User Form where a user makes a selection in a list box (called Relay).  That selection populates an option in a second list box (Called Squad) based upon the following criteria:

- The value in column "O" is not blank
- The value in column "D" IS blank
- The value in column "L" matches the user's selection in the 1st list box (Relay)

The code I have is somewhat working, however the last bullet point is the problem.  Whenever I select a "Relay" it is displaying all the blank "Squads" instead of the ones where just Column "L" matches the User Selection.  Do I have an error in the logic of my "If" statement?  I have attached some screenshots to help explain what I am attempting to accomplish.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
Private Sub lstRelayNumber_Click()

Dim Dict As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Relay As Range, vL, vD, vO
Dim RelayNumber As Long

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheets("Score Sheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
    Me.lstSquadNumber.Clear
    RelayNumber = Me.lstRelayNumber.Value
    
          
    For Each Relay In .Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Cells
       vO = Relay.Value                     'Column O value
       vD = .Range("D" & Relay.Row).Value  'Column D value
       vL = .Range("L" & Relay.Row).Value  'Column L Value
       
       
             If Len(vL) = RelayNumber And Len(vD) = 0 And Len(vO) > 0 Then
           If Not Dict.exists(vO) Then
               Dict.Add vO, 1
               lstSquadNumber.AddItem vO
           End If
        End If
       Next Relay
End With
```

End Sub

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on Mr.Excel at [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/adding-selection-to-list-box-based-upon-prior-list-box-selection.1154856/)

The answer is that there shouldn't be a "Len" in front of vL, because the LEN is returning the string length and not the value.